# Examples of vector fields directed towards origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I'm asked to state a vector field equation directed radially in towards origin, would $-\langle x,y\rangle $ suffice, or do I need to divide it by its magnitude r i.e. $-\left\langle \frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}\right\rangle $ or should I divide it by $r^2$?

Comment: Any of them will do, but if it's important, note that only $-\langle x,y \rangle$ is differentiable at the origin (the other two are not even continuous at $(0,0)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any vector field of the form
$$
F(\mathbf r) = -f(|\mathbf r|)\, \mathbf r = -f(r)\, \mathbf r \ ; \qquad f(r) > 0
$$
is directed towards the origin, where $f$ is function of one argument, and its argument here is the distance $r$ from the origin, which is the length of $|\mathbf r|$. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ we have
$$
r = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}\ ;\quad  \mathbf r = (x,y)^T
$$
one can take
\begin{align}
f(r) &= \cos^2(r^2) = \cos^2(x^2 +y^2)\\
f(r) &= \ln^2(r^2-3r) = \ln^2(x^2 +y^2-3\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}) \\
f(r) &= \frac{1}{r^3} = (x^2 +y^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \\
\end{align}
and $F(\mathbf r)$ above will be as required

Comment: Can you elaborate on this...coz my professor made the same statement and m confused by it and is the reason for this post

Comment: I'll edit it, adding examples

Answer (score 0):

Both would be directed toward the origin, one of magnitude the distance from the origin, the other of magnitude one.  Take your choice.  They are scalar multiples of one another.

So, $F(x,y)=(-x,-y)$ should suffice, say.